# Debugging ASP.NET Strings Downloaded to Browser (MontrÃ©al instead of Montréal)

Tags: asp.net, http, encoding, character-encoding, vcf-vcard

I'm downloading a [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) to the browser using Response.Write to output .NET strings with special accented characters. Mime type is **text/x-vcard** and 
French characters are appearing wrong in Outlook, for example `Montréal;Québec` .NET string shows as `MontrÃ©al  QuÃ©bec` in browser.

Apparently vCard default format is ASCII. .NET strings are Unicode UTF-16.

I'm using this [vCard generator code from CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/vcard.aspx)

I've played with the System.Encoding [sample code at the bottom of this linked MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) to convert the unicode string into bytes and then write the ascii bytes but then I get `Montr?al Qu?bec` (progress but not a win). Also I've tried setting content type to both us-ascii and utf-8 of the response.

If I open the downloaded vCard in Windows Notepad and save it as ANSI text (instead of default unicode format) and open in Outlook it's okay. So my assumption is I need to cause download of ANSI charset but am unsure if I'm doing it wrong or have a misunderstanding of where to start.

**Update:** Looking at the raw HTTP, it appears my French characters are being downloaded in the unexpected format so it looks like I need to do some work on the server side...
[raw http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/8533/charsd.png](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/8533/charsd.png)  [(full size)](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/8533/charsd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ã©` is what `é` looks like when it's encoded as UTF-8 and mistakenly decoded as ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 (or "ANSI", as Microsoft apps like to call it).  When you open the file in Notepad, it automatically detects the encoding as UTF-8.  Then you change the encoding by saving it as "ANSI", which works because `é` is supported by that encoding as well.

When you view the page in Outlook, what does the it say the encoding is?  That HTTP dump looks like well-formed UTF-8 to me, but Outlook seems to be reading it as ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252.  I don't use Outlook and I don't know its quirks; are you sure you got the headers right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert anything! Just specify in the [HTTP response headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525304.aspx) on the text/x-vcard document that the response is UTF-8 encoded (`Response.CharSet` or `Response.ContentEncoding` or similar - not sure what your specific situation is).

Also, you could try emitting an [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) to help the client determine the encoding.

Comment: Emitting UTF8 caused two bytes per some Latin chars and those vCards couldn't be interpreted. I think UTF-8 is compatible with ANSI but not ASCII. An ANSI format worked. I'm still looking into it.

Comment: Correction: I should have said I think UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII but not ANSI.

Comment: @jdk UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 - or rather, UTF-8 was designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII. When you say "couldn't be interpreted", what does that mean? By whom? And what was the error?

Comment: Pic in the question shows some two-byte sequences for French characters (e.g. Montreal) instead of one. VCard needs consistent 1 byte chars.

Comment: @jdk If you use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, it will probably work on your machine, since ISO-8859-1 contains most French characters, but only because your Windows is set to fall back to that particular 8-bit encoding when the actual encoding is unknown.